# Error: Please select at least one membership option

Tags: civicontribute

After adding a new price set, the payment page looks okay until I click Confirm Contribution. Then this error appears.

[image]

Comment: We would need to see a screenshot of your Price Set to be confident that was set up correctly, ie that each Price Option related to a membership type and hence when selected would be confirming that you had selected 'a membership type'. Other option is to replicate with a simpler Price Set on one of the demo sites, then people can see what you set up.

Comment: @Drew Did you ever resolve this?  If so, could you please post your answer?  If you're still looking for an answer, please update the question per Pete's suggestion?